# Append Input File Name to date based on condition in SSIS Variable Expression

Tags: ssis

I have couple of CSv input files with different filenames along with difeerent date formats. i need to select the input file dynamically based on a condition .

For example

```
i have files file120120909.csv, scalefile09102012.csv
```

i need to retrive the input file based on condition. So i have taken an user variable and return expression in this way

```
(@[User::Type] =="File" ? "file" : (@[User::type] =="scale" ? "scale_" :"NA"))  + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yyyy", @[System::StartTime] ) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252) DATEPART("mm", @[System::StartTime]),2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("dd", @[System::StartTime]),2)
```

when i evaluate the expression i got the following result

```
file120120912
```

now when i assign value for user variable @[User::Type] =="scale" then the expression result has to be `scalefile09102012`.

So based on condition how can i append the date for the file

Answer (score 0):

You can write the VB.NET code into the script task to solve your issue:

```
    Dim type As String = Dts.Variables("Type").Value.ToString()
    Dim startDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Dts.Variables("StartTime").Value.ToString())

    Dim result As String = ""

    If type.ToLower() = "file" Then
        result = type.ToLower() + startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    ElseIf type.ToLower() = "scale" Then
        result = type.ToLower() + "file" + startDate.ToString("MMddyyyy")
    Else
        result = "incorrect type"
    End If

    MsgBox(result)
```